# new Date("YYYY/MM") not work on IE 11

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

In my project, i use js code below to take date with date input only year and month:

```
var current_time = new Date(current);
```

with current data is something like this: "2017/04"
It work perfect on chrome but on IE 11, i get invalid date for current_time. Can your guys help to to take date form data which only has year and month like this on IE? Thankyou.

Comment: what is the current variable that you are passing in Date() ?

Comment: it is something like this:  current = "2017/04"

Comment: so you only want the month and year in ie11 ?

Comment: yeah, because my graph only show data in month

Comment: please check my answer if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates should be formatted according [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) or [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) So if you use '-' instead of '/ it will work every where.

```js
console.log(new Date("2017-04"))
```

if you want to still have your date with '/' you can do this

```js
console.log(new Date("2017/04".replace(/\//g, "-")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is not a standard format of date. Non standard date formats cause problems on various browsers like IE, safari, etc.

Use this method. It will work on all IE as well

> Run it on chrome and IE. Here in this snippet, it will give one month less since stack snippet is using a different library for date parsing.

```js
var input = "2017/04"
var year = input.split("/")[0]

// indexing starts with 0
var month = parseInt(input.split("/")[1],10) -1 

var date = new Date(year,month)
console.log(date)
```

This is what it will output on browsers including IE

```
Sat Apr 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: i think you missunderstand something, i want creat date with data is month and year only, not create data with only year and month from current_time.

Comment: @LongLý Revised my answer. Since you have not specified date. I did what your current input gives me on chrome. It works on IE as well

Comment: @LongLý Run it on chrome and IE. Here in this snippet, it will give one month less since stack snippet is using a different library for date parsing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the date by passing the month and year to dateObject you can do:

```js
current = '2017/04';
current = current.split("/")
var date = new Date(current[0], current[1]);
// it will return the date object where date is set as the first day of the month
console.log(date)
```

which will give you the date object set to the first day of the month.

If you want to get the current month and year you can do:

```js
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
date = year + '/' + month;
console.log(date);
```