# Date render in data-table and new Date() is not working in IE11 & Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is using datatable in which i use render date function it works in chrome but it shows NaN in IE11 & Safari. Pls help me how to resolve this issue
Here is my code snippet
**Datatable**

```
 {
    "data": 'starttime',
    "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " - " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
    }
}
```

**Js code**

```
var date = new Date(driver_data[i].starttime);
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
ps = (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " - " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

Comment: What is your date format ?? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316829/new-dateyyyy-mm-not-work-on-ie-11

Comment: @Shree this the date which i get from server "2019-03-18T12:30:00.000+0530"

Comment: Just give date without time like `2019-03-18` and it's fine.

Comment: @Shree i get this date from api response & i want to display date & time both as per requirement. I tried with using .replace(/\//g, "-"), but not working

Comment: So you need to split date and time and hold that on some variable and pass only date part for new date and concatenate  again for final result.

Comment: Could you pls help me with an example using my code

Comment: See this fiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/do2yb63n/

Comment: @Shree not working showing an error "cannot read property split of null"

Comment: Naaaa ie support split function see . Just ensure dt is not empty like fiddle example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422355/javascript-split-function-not-working-in-ie

Comment: I tested on IE and it's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older versions of Safari, IE do not support parsing of ISO format string dates and therefore you are getting the `NaN` errors. You could implement your own [parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802461/javascript-which-browsers-support-parsing-of-iso-8601-date-string-with-date-par) or just use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library which makes it a whole lot easier.

```
{
    "data": 'starttime',
    "render": function (data) {
        return moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY-hh:mm");
    }
}
```

Here are more ways to [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: how i use moment in code "var date = new Date(driver_data[i].starttime);
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
ps = (month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " - " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
    "title": "D.O.B",
    "data": "dob",
    "render": function (data) {
         var d = new Date(data),
         month = d.getMonth() + 1,
         day = d.getDate(),
         year = d.getFullYear(),
         hour = d.getHours(),
         minutes = d.getMinutes(),
         seconds = d.getSeconds();
         return day + ' &ndash; ' + month + ' &ndash; ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;        
     }
}
```

Comment: The code which I shared is working fine in IE & safari, I think you need to check the Date format properly