# Date format is working in chrome but not in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, momentjs

I need to set and get date. I am setting the date using below format
`new Date('01/01/2019').toISOString()`.But it shows me 01/01/1919 in IE11 and in chrome works fine.

I tried

```
moment('01/01/2019').format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

and few other ways but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of moment?

Comment: "moment": "^2.24.0",

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new Date("YYYY/MM") not work on IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316829/new-dateyyyy-mm-not-work-on-ie-11)

Comment: No I tried that solution didnt work for me

Comment: I've tried to reproduce with `moment` and using IE version `11.592.18362.0` and moment version `2.24.0` the returned value was the same as chrome: `2019-01-01T00:00:00.000`.

Comment: let dateValue  = moment(this.releaseDetails.startDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

.................setValue(new Date(dateValue)) doesn't work for me
but setValue(new Date('01-01-2020')) works for me. I don't know whats going on

Comment: My test result is the same with Diogo's. And I also think you should use '-' instead of '/' in date format. Besides, I noticed that you have already opened a question which is the same with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59970216/angular-date-picker-showing-wrong-year-in-ieinstead-of-2019-its-showing-1919. I suggest you to focus on one question and delete the duplicate one.

Answer (score 1):

Use valid ISO8601 string format if possible:

```js
new Date('2019-01-01').toISOString();
```